# Is it possible to search for a multiple keywords at once in a dictionairy?

Tags: python

I was wondering if it is possible to search for multiple keywords in the dictionary "keywords". For this example, I want it to generate the response if the keywords "generate" and "name" was included into the input.

```
import random

keywords = {
"generate"+"name": ["Joe", "Bob", "Tim"],
}

def generate_response(user_input):
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in user_input.lower():
            return random.choice(keywords[keyword])
    return "I'm sorry, I didn't understand what you said."

# Define a main function to run the chatbot
def main():
    print("Chatbot: Hi, I'm a Chatbot. How can I help you today?")
    while True:
        user_input = input("You: ")
        if user_input.lower() == "quit":
            break
        response = generate_response(user_input)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print("Chatbot:", response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `"generate"+"name"` is just `"generatename"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I came up with:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

class TupleDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, Sequence) and not isinstance(key, str):
            return super().__getitem__(tuple(sorted(key)))
        else:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, Sequence) and not isinstance(key, str):
            super().__setitem__(tuple(sorted(key)), value)
        else:
            super().__setitem__(key, value)


keywords = TupleDict()
keywords["generate", "name"] = ["Joe", "Bob", "Tim"]
keywords["generate", "day"] = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]
keywords["pet"] = "cat"
print(keywords["pet"])
print(keywords["name", "generate"])
```

Whenever we refer to an element of this dict, the key will under-the-hood get converted into a sorted tuple, which will allow us to ignore the order of keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one key for each dictionary item. A simple way to search for two (or more) words in a key would be to use a tuple as the key. Then if the user inputs all the parts of the key then return the required response:

```
keywords = {('generate', 'name'): ['fred', 'joe']}

def generate_response(user_input):
    for keyword in keywords:
        if all(keyw in user_input.lower() for keyw in keyword):
            return random.choice(keywords[keyword])
    return "I'm sorry, I didn't understand what you said."
```

A benefit of this approach is that the input order does not matter so 'generate name' or 'name generate' are both accepted and also extended input such as 'generated name' is accepted. The approach can be extended to more than 2 words such as ('show', 'first', 'name') for the dictionary key.